# Custom port for SSH client in $HOME/.ssh/config doesn't work

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm using a config file for my OpenSSH client instead of defining options in command line whenever needed, sample from my config file:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
```

---- TOP PARTS REDACTED HERE ----

```
Host hmnw
        Hostname hmnw.mydomain.com 
        User myname
        Port 60022
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

When I try to ssh to this host:

```
$ ssh hmnw
```

It doesn't work.

But when I do

```
$ ssh -p 60022 hmnw
```

It goes through.

Out of curiosity, I did `strace` on this process:

```
$ ssh hmnw&
$ sudo strace -p $!
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(22), sin_addr=inet_addr("XX.XX.XX.XX")}, 16
```

I understand it is trying to connect to default SSH port 22.

Note: Changed my actual hostname and IP address above.

What am I doing wrong?

My ssh version

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Adding this after @muru's suggestion

```
$ ssh -vvvv hmnw                                                            
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/myname/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/myname/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/myname/.ssh/config line 21: Applying options for hmnw
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "hmnw.mydomain.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to hmnw.mydomain.com [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
```

Comment: Add the output of `ssh -v hmnv` please.

Comment: @muru Added -vvvv output. Thanks for reminder

Comment: Methinks you are not telling us everything; especially when you say you provide a "sample" of your configuration file, you may have omitted something significant. Also, I am pretty certain you are not actually running the command `ssh -p hmnw`.

Comment: @fkraiem my mistake I omitted port there

Comment: @fkraiem [This is how I log in manually](http://imgur.com/a/quDvi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the offender piece in configuration, it is my mistake based on an assumption:

Top of my `~/.ssh/config` file

```
### default for all ##
Host *
     ForwardAgent no
     ForwardX11 no
     ForwardX11Trusted yes
     User myname
     Port 2222
     Protocol 2
     ServerAliveInterval 30
     ServerAliveCountMax 120
```

Port `2222` here was overriding Port `60022` below which belongs to `hmnw`.

I removed `Port 2222` from `Host *` , now it works.

Update:
As per @muru's suggestion, moving default config from top to bottom of `config` file allows me to use custom port entry for default `*`

@steeldriver's suggestion `Host * !hmnw` is also useful, I don't have a use case for it yet but I can see it would allow me to negate certain settings for particular host, if I needed to.

Comment: Keep the default `Host *` stanza at the end of the file.

Comment: IIRC you can use negations to exclude certain hosts from wildcard matches e.g. `Host * !hmnw` - see [Stop ssh config on first match](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152265/65304)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that **ssh** (on ubuntu 16.04) doesn't not use ~/.ssh/config by default which contradict the guide on [OpenSSH client configuration](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/), saying that

> Command-line options take precedence over configuration files. The user-specific configuration file ~/.ssh/config is used next. Finally, the global /etc/ssh/ssh_config file is used. The first obtained value for each configuration parameter will be used.

While the following two solutions still work:

1. `sudo ssh -F ~/.ssh/config the_name_after_Host`
2. put the configuration lines in file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (at the beginning of the file) instead of `~/.ssh/config`